# Determine snap ended event in android recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using LinearSnapHelper to snap to the next item in the recycler view.
I need to take an action if the snap is successful. By successful I mean snap succesfully showed the next item. So, I am looking for an event that says that the snap is successful and next item is shown. Is there such an event to which I can listen to , to take appropriate action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a custom `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` and `findSnapView` for that 
by doing extension function on the `SnapHelper`

```
fun SnapHelper.getSnapPosition(recyclerView: RecyclerView): Int {
    val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager ?: return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
    val snapView = findSnapView(layoutManager) ?: return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
    return layoutManager.getPosition(snapView)
}
```

here is the full code

create an interface to be as a callback

```
interface OnSnapPositionChangeListener {
fun onSnapPositionChange(position: Int)
}
```

override `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()`

```
class SnapOnScrollListener(private var mSnapHelper: SnapHelper, private var mOnSnapPositionChangeListener: OnSnapPositionChangeListener) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
private var snapPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION

override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
    val snapPosition = mSnapHelper.getSnapPosition(recyclerView)
    val snapPositionChanged = this.snapPosition != snapPosition && snapPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
    if (snapPositionChanged) {
        mOnSnapPositionChangeListener
                .onSnapPositionChange(snapPosition)
        this.snapPosition = snapPosition
    }

}
}

      var  helper = LinearSnapHelper()
        recyclerview.onFlingListener = null
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerview)


recyclerview.addOnScrollListener( SnapOnScrollListener(helper, object : OnSnapPositionChangeListener {
        override fun onSnapPositionChange(position: Int) {
            //your code

        }
    }))
```